# How can I type macrons?

Tags: discussion, support, faq, formatting, macrons

I'd like to type macrons on (OS X | Windows | Ubuntu | other), but my keyboard doesn't have an `ā` key. How can I add macrons to my vowels?

I don't want to copy them from this strangely convenient list: `ā` `ē` `ī` `ō` `ū` `ȳ`.

Answer (score 15):

On **OS X**, it's easy. Just hold down the vowel you want and select the macron-ized version: ā.

[image]

If you're typing a lot of these, I'd recommend adding "ABC Extended" as a keyboard layout (in System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources. Now you can type <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, then the vowel: ā ē ī

[image]

---

Or, if you like, you can copy them from here: `ā` `ē` `ī` `ō` `ū` `ȳ`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "hold down"? Surely not the physical key?

Comment: Yes, the physical key @Cerberus. Might need to toggle a setting somewhere to enable it instead of repeating.

Comment: Hey, hello! Hmm I see, so you have to hold down the u key, then perform certain actions to 'select' ū. It's good to have an as option, I'm sure! But I find Autohotkey to be quite a bit more efficient, no offence!

Answer (score 9):

I use HTML entities:

`&amacr;` ā
`&emacr;` ē
`&imacr;` ī
`&omacr;` ō
`&umacr;` ū

Oddly, you can't just substitute `y` into any of the above. You'll need

`&#x233;` ȳ

Which is unfortunately not so easy.

Comment: Looks like you can use, e.g., `&Amacr;` for capital vowels.

Comment: Similarly, `&#x232;` should work for capital 'y'.

Answer (score 7):

On **Windows**, there does not seem to be a simple way for direct entry of macron vowels that is enabled by default. [Matt Gutting's HTML entities](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12/21) are a pretty good option for questions and answers, but they appear not to work in comments.

The "most straightforward" method for direct insertion of Unicode characters appears to be the second approach described [here](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/08/17/three-ways-to-enter-unicode-characters-in-windows/), which involves modifying the registry (not for the faint of heart!) and then logging out and back in (or rebooting).

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open the "Run..." dialog
2. Enter `regedit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to load the registry editor

[image: Run dialog for regedit]
<sub>*Click images here and below for larger versions*</sub>

3. In Registry Editor, browse to the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Input Method`

[image: Regedit nav to Input Method key]

4. Right-click and select `New` > `String Value`

[image: Right-click and add new string value]

5. Name the new string value `EnableHexNumpad`

[image: Naming the new value]

6. Double-click the new value, enter `1` as the value, and click `OK`
7. Close the Registry Editor
8. Log out and back in, or reboot.

The Unicode characters can then be entered by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>, pressing the following key sequences, then releasing <kbd>Alt</kbd>.  The leading <kbd>+</kbd> is the keypad 'plus' in all cases, and letters are entered using the regular keyboard keys:

Ā: `+0100`
Ē: `+0112`
Ī: `+012a`
Ō: `+014c`
Ū: `+016a`
Ȳ: `+0232`

ā: `+0101`
ē: `+0113`
ī: `+012b`
ō: `+014d` (this one messes up because <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> activates the address bar :-/ )
ū: `+016b`
ȳ: `+0233`

Comment: @ElliotA. Agreed, for most users Matt Gutting's approach is far superior. I'd already gotten most of the way through working up the post before he posted his, though, so I just went ahead and finished it. <shrug>

Comment: Frankly, I concur with the -1 vote total on this answer at present. :-D

Comment: Inventive! Even though this is probably less practical in most cases, it is good to know that it is possible.

Comment: @Cerberus Yeah, opening up Alt-key access to the full Unicode character set promises to be terrifically handy in a wide variety of contexts.

Comment: @ElliotA. I see no possible way that this could "ruin" a computer; just because it involves modifying the registry does not mean that potential destruction can follow. I for one find this method incredibly useful; I need to be able to type a variety of accents, diacritics, etc., to which I need to be able to assign custom keys, which the default Windows keyboards (like the Maori keyboard) can't provide.

Comment: @EthanBierlein wow, that was a comment from a while ago.  I was completely wrong, I realize that now.

Comment: I know this is an ancient post at this point, but I just wanted to chime in and say that for my use-case, this is the superior method for Windows because it's native and can be used for Discord, Word Processors, etc. — it's not limited to things that are able to render HTML entities.

Answer (score 7):

For Windows users, the Maori (New Zealand) keyboard allows easy addition of macrons to all vowels except *y*.

From the Control Panel, go to Region and Language, then click Change Keyboards..., then Add.  Then select Maori's keyboard:

[image: Maori keyboard]

Enabling this keyboard modifies the behavior of the <kbd>`</kbd> key:

[image: Affected key]

Tap <kbd>`</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> to get `ā`.  Tap <kbd>`</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> to get the grave accent itself.

Comment: You could also install the keyboard for Latvian.  With the Latvian QWERTY keyboard in Windows, you add macrons using the alt key, although there is no long 'y' either.

Comment: @neubau - Since ō is not used in the Latvian language, in the Latvian QWERTY keyboard in Windows Alt Gr + o gives the Estonian / Livonian letter õ.

Answer (score 7):

The most convenient way I've ever seen happens on Linux. You can use the compose key. Then you simply type `Compose, -, o` to get an ō. Or you type `Compose, ^, o` to get an ô.

Beautiful in its simplicity.

Besides, should you be learning Greek, you can setup your own `.XCompose` so as to be able to denote the vowel length in the Greek alphabet (not sure if it's enabled by default)

Comment: Nice!  Too bad it does not work in Emacs(23).  The response: `<Multi_key> is undefined`

Comment: Note that by default in X, 'Compose' is Shift+Alt Gr. If you're typing latin a lot, it's probably worth remapping it to just Alt Gr, or left Ctrl, or something. There are various ways of doing this!

Answer (score 6):

The most *convenient* way to type macra in Windows is by using the marvellous programme **[Autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/)**. If you install Autohotkey and run the following script at startup, you can easily type macros by typing `e-=-` etc. Advantages:

- Easily **adjustable** to your preferences.
- You don't need to reach for faraway or **unusual keys** on your keyboard to type a special character.
- You don't need to **hold down any modifier keys**.
- You can add the macron **after** you have already typed the vowel. So you type `para`, then you think, oh, I wanted a macron on that a, so you type `-=-` (or whichever characters you have set up) and it appears. You can also type `parare`, then backspace twice, then `-=-` and it will appear on the `a` you typed earlier.
- You can do this for **any character** you often type. I also have e.g. `e\/` set up to turn into `ĕ`, etc. I can give you my full script in case you're interested.

You can of course change the `-=-` into anything you want. Just make sure it is a combination you don't normally type. Just to be sure, you can make the hotkeys work only in certain windows, for example:

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2

#If Winactive("Firefox Latin Language Stack Exchange")
or Winactive("the title of some other window")

:*?:a-=-::ā
:*?:e-=-::ē
:*?:i-=-::ī
:*?:o-=-::ō
:*?:u-=-::ū
:*?:y-=-::ȳ
```

Copy-paste this code into a text file, then save the file as a unicode file (the format should probably be UTF-8) with an extension `.ahk` and have it run on startup.

You can also make it type words or sentences by adding lines like this:

```
:*?:tllqq::Thesaurus Linguae Latinae
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a HTML entity that puts a macron on the preceding character: `&#772;` (also `&#x304;`).
For example, `A&#772;` becomes Ā and `y&#772;` becomes ȳ.
It is hard to remember, but on the other hand it works with any letter.

The [breve counterpart](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/172/79) is `&#774;` (also `&#x306;`).
With these you can easily speak about vowel length in general: V̄ is longer than V̆.

Answer (score 1):

in **emacs**

**M-x set-input-method latin-alt-postfix**

type

ama-re, amo-, ama-s, amat, ama-mus, ama-tis, amant

get

amāre, amō, amās, amat, amāmus, amātis, amant

Answer (score 1):

On **Android** there is a actual **Latīna** keyboard:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=klye.plugin.la&hl=en_US

It's a plugin for the multiling-O keyboard app, which you also need to install.

It's a bit 'busy' by default, but if you fiddle with the settings you can cut it all down to a nice qwerty+macrons arrangement.

Answer (score 1):

For **Linux Mint** (I think it will also work for other distributions, but I didn't check) you can create a custom keyboard layout.

This custom layout will let you press **RightAlt** (careful, it doesn't work with **LeftAlt**) and a vowel to get that same vowel with a macron.
For example:
**RightAlt+a** results in 'ā'.
**RightAlt+Shift+a** results in 'Ā'.
etc.

I used this [site](https://www.kavalier.tv/blog/custom-keyboard-layout-for-coding-on-ubuntu-linux) as a reference for what I'll write next.

**Tutorial starts here**
We will derive this custom layout from **English (US)**.
To do this use this command `cd /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`.
Then use your preferred editor to create a file named `latinmacrons` in which you should paste this text:

```
default partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "basic" {
   include "us"

    name[Group1]="Latin (Custom Layout)";

    key <AC01> { [            a,           A,            U0101,       U0100 ] };
    key <AD03> { [            e,           E,            U0113,       U0112 ] };
    key <AD08> { [            i,           I,            U012B,       U012A ] };
    key <AD09> { [            o,           O,            U014D,       U014C ] };
    key <AD07> { [            u,           U,            U016B,       U016A ] };
    key <AD06> { [            y,           Y,            U0233,       U0232 ] };

    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
};
```

Save the file and exit your editor.
Now use this command `cd /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules` and open the file `evdev.xml` with your editor.
Inside `evdev.xml` search for `</layoutList>` and insert above it this text:

```
<layout>
  <configItem>
    <name>latinmacrons</name>
    <shortDescription>Latin (Custom Layout)</shortDescription>
    <description>Latin (Custom Layout)</description>
    <languageList>
      <iso639Id>lat</iso639Id>
    </languageList>
  </configItem>
  <variantList>
  </variantList>
</layout>
```

Save the document and reboot.

After the reboot you should find your layout among the other layouts in the keyboard settings.
It should be named **Latin (Custom Layout)**, just select it.
Alternatively you can use `setxkbmap -layout latinmacrons` to test the layout .

Now you should be able to write macrons using **RightAlt** in combination with the desired vowel.