# How can I write two rows of text with aligned words?

Tags: support, formatting

Suppose I want to write a passage in Latin and a word-by-word translation below so that the corresponding English word is directly below the Latin counterpart?

Something like a table with one word per cell would do the trick, but tables do not seem to be supported.
Another option would be to use preformatted text:

```
Caesar  non  canebat   Graece.
Caesar  not  did sing  in Greek.
```

The problem with preformatted text (apart from a slightly unsatisfactory typeface) is that I can't use html character entities for macrons or other special characters.

This does not look good:

```
Caesar  n&omacr;n  can&emacr;bat  Graec&emacr;.
Caesar  not        did sing       in Greek.
```

In plain text it looks good (Caesar  nōn  canēbat   Graecē) but I can't align the words.
For me at least html character entities are the preferred way to input special characters.

I think I could work around this using MathJax, but that's really not what it's made for and I don't see a reason to activate it for this site.
For those of you that are not familiar with MathJax, it allows you to type formulas (like $e^{i\pi}+1=0$) neatly in your posts and it works on mathematically oriented SE sites.

Comment: On a side note, you could install Autohotkey and have `&omacr;` be converted automatically and instantly into `ō`. That way, you can use macra in `monospace text` without having to change your routine (which I think is important: everybody hates being forced to learn something new when the old thing served him just fine). For instructions on Autohotkey, see Nathaniel's link on how to type macra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preformatted text is basically the only option for this.  See [Is there any markdown to create tables?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73566/300411)

You can include macrons in preformatted text by using the actual characters instead of the html entities:

`ā ē ī ō ū ȳ`
`Caesar  nōn  canēbat    Graecē`
`Caesar  not  did sing   in Greek`

Several methods for getting these macron characters easily are found here: [How can I type macrons?](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2/12)

If you really must have a pretty layout, then the only option is to get an image of it (such as with screenshot software) and include the image in your post.

Comment: Thanks! I feared this would be the best option. I just realized that I can type vowels with macrons in the plain text and then copy and paste them from the preview back to the text box. Then I just have to remember the entity code (which I already do) without copying characters from some external sources.

Comment: Yes, that's a handy trick if you want to stick to using the html entities.