# How to type a breve?

Tags: discussion, support, faq, formatting

Sometimes when I want to emphasize that a vowel is short, it is not enough not to write a [macron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macron), and I need to add a [breve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breve).
How can I do that?

The [earlier question about typing macrons](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2/79) does not discuss adding a breve.

Answer (score 3):

My [solution using Autohotkey](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/a/102/30) works for any Unicode character (or basically any action you'd like to take on your computer), so also for brevia. I just type whatever combination or sequence of keys I have chosen to get a breve. I have set `a\/` for *ă*, as it is easy to remember. (You can guess how I type â.) No modifier keys, no combinations that are hard to remember.

The Autohotkey code required is as follows, to be changed at your pleasure:

```
:*?:a\/::ă
:*?:e\/::ĕ
:*?:i\/::ĭ
:*?:o\/::ŏ
:*?:u\/::ŭ
:*?:y\/::ў
```

You can basically add any character you like by copy-pasting the last line and copy-pasting a Unicode character you have found on e.g. Wikipaedia instead of ў, and typing some easy-to-remember key sequence instead of `y\/`. That's how I usually add new characters. But there are even easier ways (ask me).

Answer (score 2):

You can use html entities, but they are less convenient than for macrons:

> Ă `&#258;`
>   ă `&#259;`
>   Ĕ `&#276;`
>   ĕ `&#277;`
>   Ĭ `&#300;`
>   ĭ `&#301;`
>   Ŏ `&#334;`
>   ŏ `&#335;`
>   Ŭ `&#364;`
>   ŭ `&#365;`
>   Ῠ `&#8168;`
>   ў `&#1118;`

For macrons there is an alternative way that is easier to remember (ā is `&amacr;` or `&#257;`), but for a breve the only option seems to be to use numbers.

The Y in the list above is a bit of a hack: I took the lower case y from the Cyrillic and upper case Y from the Greek alphabet.
I did not find a Y with breve for the Latin alphabet in the html entities.

Another option is to simply copy from the list above.

**Added note:**
You can add a breve to any letter with `&#x306;` or `&#774;`.
This leaves you with only one entity code to remember and it can be easily combined with any character.
(Suggested by Mr Lister in comments.)

> y̆ `y&#x306;`
>   Y̆ `Y&#x306;`
>   ă `a&#x306;`
>   q̆ `q&#x306;`

Comment: If the Unicode character doesn't exist, that's a surefire sign that no language in the world uses it! Anyway, a better method than putting  letters from Cyrillic or Greek in your text is to just type the letter and the reference for the combining character behind it. So `y&#x306;` will work beautifully to produce a y with a breve.

Comment: @MrLister, thanks! That works well. Don't over-interpret the sign though; Latin does use it (in special cases), but for some reason it is not implemented the way other vowels with breve are. Nevertheless, a separate entity code for the breve is very handy.

Answer (score 2):

When I'm writing Latin I usually use the ABC Extended keyboard layout (in System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources), as @Undo suggested in the answers to the linked question. In that layout, Option-B or Alt-B (depending on your OS) adds a breve to whatever vowel you type next.

(I wish I had @Undo's facility with display so that I could make this answer show exactly how this worked, but, alas, I am merely mortal.)