# Formatting sandbox

Tags: support, formatting

The sole purpose of this question is to provide you with a testing ground for formatting.
Feel free to post an answer below to test anything like links, pictures, subtitles, tables, or quotes.

See also [the formatting help page](https://latin.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

This answer contains samples of different formatting options.
To see how something is done, simply click the "edit" button under this answer and copy the code from there.
**Please do not edit this question for testing purposes. Instead, copy things from here and post a separate answer to test.**
If you want an example of something here, please ask in a comment.

---

The editor has many tools.
Try them out below in your own answer!

---

## Header level 1

### Header level 2

#### Header level 3

##### Header level 4

###### Header level 5

###### Header level 6

If you really need six levels of titles and subtitles, you are not writing a Q&A post.

---

Some but not all HTML tags and entities work…

---

Quote with two paragraphs:

> Some text.
>
> Some more text. Note the `>` starting the empty line. If you remove it, you get two separate quote boxes.

Spoiler (content shown only when you click or tap):

> Hector dies.

---

| Derivation examples | From noun | From verb | From adjective |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| To noun | *navis > navicula* | *canere > cantor* | *audax > audacia* |
| To verb | *laus > laudare* | *edere > esurire* | *novus > novare* |
| To adjective | *aurum > aureus* | *audere > audax* | *fessus > fessulus* |

---

See separate pages for inserting a [macron](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2/79) or a [breve](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/172/79).

Two ways of creating links are above.
The target addresses can be given

1. as a list at the end (macron example) or
2. immediately withing the text (breve example).